How can i give my AppLifecycleListener BuildContext?
I need inside my AppLifecycleListener context to execute cubit functions. How can put BuildContext inside my Listener of AppLifecycleListener?
_listener = AppLifecycleListener(
  onStateChange: _handleStateChange,
);

I need context inside _handleStateChange. When I put it like this
_handleStateChange(BuildContext context)

Give me the following Error:

The argument type 'void Function(AppLifecycleState, BuildContext)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(AppLifecycleState)?'


You can't assign _handleStateChange to onStateChange, their types are different, how about just call _handleStateChange like this
    _listener = AppLifecycleListener(
      onStateChange: (state) {
        _handleStateChange(context);
      },
    );


That does not work really. Right now i get "Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct Provider". The context is not the right one i think. In my build Widget i already use BlocProvider<PlayerEnergyCubit>(         create: (context) => So the context should be there.
